# Unity error--- Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IUserRepository, key ""

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, unity-container, shrinkr

I am trying to run MVC sample project  [Shrinkr](http://shrinkr.codeplex.com) downloaded from codeplex

I actually opened this solution in VS2012 and is compiling successfully. But when I run this application ,I am getting this error .

I am getting an exception error message stating "Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IUserRepository, key ""
"

Pasted below is the detailed exception message

```
   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IUserRepository, key ""
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService]()
       at Shrinkr.Web.CreateDefaultUsers.ExecuteCore(IServiceLocator serviceLocator) in c:\Users\RON\Downloads\Shrinkr\Shrinkr.Web.Common\BootstrapperTask\CreateDefaultUsers.cs:line 19
       at System.Web.Mvc.Extensibility.BootstrapperTask.Execute(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Extensibility.Bootstrapper.Execute()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Extensibility.ExtendedMvcApplication.Application_Start()
  InnerException: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Shrinkr.Repositories.IUserRepository", name = "". Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.UserRepository, null]) failed: The parameter databaseFactory could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.UserRepository(Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.IQueryFactory queryFactory). (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
       Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
       TypeRequested=IUserRepository
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerBase.Resolve(Type t)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Extensibility.Unity.UnityAdapter.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
            at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
       InnerException: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException
            HResult=-2146233088
            Message=The current build operation (build key Build Key[Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.UserRepository, null]) failed: The parameter databaseFactory could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.UserRepository(Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.IQueryFactory queryFactory). (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
            Source=Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
            BuildKey=Build Key[Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.UserRepository, null]
            ExecutingStrategyIndex=3
            ExecutingStrategyTypeName=BuildPlanStrategy
            StackTrace:
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.Builder.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetime, IPolicyList policies, IStrategyChain strategies, Object buildKey, Object existing)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name)
            InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
                 HResult=-2146233079
                 Message=The parameter databaseFactory could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.UserRepository(Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.IQueryFactory queryFactory).
                 Source=Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
                 StackTrace:
                      at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForResolutionFailed(Exception inner, String parameterName, String constructorSignature, IBuilderContext context)
                      at BuildUp_Shrinkr.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.UserRepository(IBuilderContext )
                      at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                      at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                      at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 InnerException: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException
```

appreciate your suggestions to make it working

Answer (score 0):

Strictly I'm not sure what problem it is, according to my experience, if you download a stable sample but unable to run it，mostly it could be reference problem.

So, you may check is that missing any DLL files and make sure their path is Asset/Plugins. Then, check *Edit-ProjectSettings-Player-YourTargetPlatform-OtherSettings*, confirm that Api Compatibility Level is set to .NET2.0(default is the subset).

Hope it works, good luck :)